# Sending a Link in an Email using PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to automate sending out the link for Google Reviews in an email after a job is closed out.

Problem is, the link that gets sent is not a hyperlink and I feel that customers are less likely to review if it's not an easy click.

My code is the below, using a button and the OnSelect command of the button:

```
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    DataCardValue3 & ";" & "darren@XXXXXXXX.com", // To
    "Review Request for " & DataCardValue1 & " " & DataCardValue2, // Subject
    "Hello " & DataCardValue1 & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "We hope that you enjoy your XXXXXXXXXX product and appreciate you helping me grow my small business. Please consider leaving us a review!" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "**https://g.page/r/XXXXXXXXXXXX/review**" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Thank You!" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Darren XXXX" & "<br>" & "President" & "<br>" & "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    // Body
)
```

My code works as far as sending the email. It's just not a hyperlink. It comes as just standard text that you would have to copy and paste into a browser.

Comment: Does it support some HTML ? Because a link could be done in an <a> tag normally. 
Such as :  <a href="url">link text</a> with the href being the location for the link, and the link text is the words you want displayed for the link.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this by using HTML tags, particularly the  tag as such :

```
<a href="url">link text</a> 

"url" being the link you want to redirect
and "link text" being the text you want displayed for the link
```